# Question regarding proof of range of a cos(x) + b sin(x)

Tags: functions, trigonometry

The proof for the range of $a \cos(x) + b \sin(x)$ given in my book is as follows

$$f(x) = a \cos(x) + b \sin(x)$$
$$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\cdot \cos(x) + \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\cdot \sin(x))$$
$$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}(\sin(\alpha)\cdot\cos(x) + \cos(\alpha)\cdot\sin(x)$$
$$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\cdot\sin(\alpha + x)$$

Similarly the same thing is done as follows

$$f(x) = a \cos(x) + b \sin(x)$$
$$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\cdot \cos(x) + \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\cdot \sin(x))$$
$$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}(\cos(\alpha)\cdot\cos(x) + \sin(\alpha)\cdot\sin(x)$$
$$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\cdot\cos(x - \alpha)$$

Then,

$$-1 \leq \sin(x + a) \leq 1$$
$$-\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \leq \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\cdot\sin(x + \alpha) \leq \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$

Therefore the range of the function is $[-\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}, \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}]$

The main issues for me in the above proof are that how can we replace $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$ and $\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$ with $\sin(\alpha)$ and $\cos(\alpha)$ or with $\cos(\alpha) or \sin(\alpha)$ and how can we make sure that they are sines and cosines of the same angle.

Even more importantly why choose the term $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ could something else have not been chosen.

And another thing does a graphical proof for this using the unit circle exists as that would be more pleasing.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: The main reason for why we can replace $x:=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and $y:=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ with $\sin(\alpha)$ and $\cos(\alpha)$(or the other way around), and the reason why we choose the term $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is to ensure that $x^2+y^2=1$. This means that points $(x, y)$ lie on the unit circle, and the angle($\alpha$) can be naturally defined by the unit circle.

Comment: @JoshuaWoo what you say i understand however how can we say the $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} and \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$ are sines and cosines of the same angle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: draw a right angled triangle with side lengths $a$ and $b$. Calculate sine and cosine for an angle of your choice.

Comment: this doesn't help much with what the question is specifically asking.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, please explain.

Comment: Thanks now i understand the subsitution in the original proof, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @infinitezero i seem to have no issues so why does he?

Answer (score 1):

The target is to express $a\cos{x}+b\sin x$ as $r_1\sin(\alpha+x)$ or, $r_2\cos(\beta-x)$ so

$$r_1\cos\alpha\sin x+r_1\sin\alpha\cos x=r_2\cos\beta\cos x+r_2\sin\beta\sin x=acosx+bsinx$$
Comparing coefficients,
$r_1\cos\alpha=r_2\sin\beta=b\\ r_1\sin\alpha=r_2\cos\beta=a$

Squaring and adding $r_1^2=r_2^2=a^2+b^2\\ \tan\alpha=\cot\beta$ hence $\alpha \;\text{and} \; \beta \; \text{are  the complementary angles of the same right angled triangle with two sides}\; a,b \; \text{hypotenuse} \; r_1=r_2$